# checkbox javascript shows status

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

what is problem with this script? i just want to show checkbox status in innerHTML that show "yes" after click on button, if it is checked, otherwise it shown "no".

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<input id="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="Terms" value="agree" ><br>
<input type="button" value="button" onClick="myFunction()" >

<script>
function myFunction() {

 var box = document.getElementById("chkbox");
 if(checkbox.checked)
  {
  var checked.value = "yes";
    var txt = checked.value;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
   }
   else if(checkbox.unchecked)
{
  var unchecked.value = "no";
  var txt = unchecked.value;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}

   }
 </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: There's no `checkbox.unchecked`. If the `checkbox.checked` isn't true, then it's not checked -- you don't have to look at another property.

Comment: I've never seen `unchecked` property for checkboxes!

Comment: what is this `var checked.value = "yes";`? Your `var box` is used nowhere. too much mistakes...

Comment: You need to define like `var unchecked = {
            value: "no"
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

- You assigned element to `box` not to `checkbox`
- There is nothing like `checkbox.unchecked`
- var name `checked.value` is not correct format.

Here is code:

```
function myFunction() {
   var box = document.getElementById("chkbox");
   if (box.checked) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "yes";
   } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "no";
   }
}
```

[Here is working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GTkQ9/)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems.

1. There is no variable with the name `checkbox`
2. The syntax `var checked.value = "yes";` is invalid

Try

```
<input type="button" value="button" onClick="myFunction()">
```

then

```
function myFunction() {
    var box = document.getElementById("chkbox");
    box.value = box.checked ? "yes" : 'no';
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = box.value;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YaV9A/)

---

Since jQuery tag is used include jQuery library in the page then

```
<input type="button" value="button" id="button">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    //cache the elements for future use
    var $chk = $('#chkbox'), // id-selector
        $demo = $('#demo');
    //click event handler
    $('#button').click(function () {
        //use is() and :checked-selector to check whether the checkbox is checked and use .text() to set the display text of the p element
        $demo.text($chk.is(':checked') ? 'yes' : 'no')
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2KDgZ/)

Comment: @Barmar sorry might be something happened when I copied it to fiddle

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
    var box = document.getElementById("chkbox");
    if(box.checked)
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'yes'
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'no';
    }
}
```

The problems in your code were:

- You set the variable `box`, but then used `checkbox.checked` instead of `box.checked`.
- You looked for `checkbox.unchecked`. There's no such property; if `.checked` isn't true, then the box is unchecked.
- You tried to declare variables `checked.value` and `unchecked.value`. Variable names can't contain `.`, that's used for specifying object properties when accessing a variable whose value is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
function myFunction() {
      if(document.getElementById('chkbox').checked) {
        alert("checked");
    } else {
       alert("not checked")
    }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want javascript alert bro, i just want to show the status in innerHTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,Shorthand

```
function myFunction(){
    var box = document.getElementById("chkbox").checked;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = box ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
```